# I can not remove the white space between the <img> images that sets the default blogger

Tags: image

I can not remove the white space between the images (below and above) that sets bloggers by default, even if I write:

```
<img src = "image.png" vspace = "0" />
```

Not even with:

```
<img src = "image.png" style = "vspace: 0" />
```

I added the  tag between the  tags of the blogger HTML but it does not even go:

```
<Style>
img {vspace: 0;}
</ Style>
```

Can you help me? Thank you